# NativeScript Angular2 Passing context parameter for data binding a function

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding, nativescript

I have been looking through the documentation and examples but cannot seem to find an appropriate example to pass the source entity to a function for  binding.

For example, in trying to bind the "`hidden`" visibility parameter value to the result of function `isHidden()`, I would like to pass some sort of variable like `callerContext` that knows which `TextField` is is associated with the binding. Does such a variable exist or do I have create a scheme myself?

```
<TextField class="input" hint="Email address" [hidden]="isHidden(callerContext)"
keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"
[(ngModel)]="contactSettings.emailAddressList[0]" returnKeyType="next" (returnPress)="focusNext()">
</TextField>
```

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: These are the documentation for textfield in angular with nativescript. https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/text-field https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield#visibility  In your case for visibility you can use ng-if similar to here https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/ng-directives

Comment: Thanks for the references. I had read these. I was more looking for existence of some predefined source variables to link things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a variable named `callerContext` until you define one. If you want the textfield reference in `isHidden` method, then pass the textfield itself

```
<TextField #txt class="input" hint="Email address" [hidden]="isHidden(txt)" ....
```

Comment: Ok, that is what I found so far. I was hoping to avoid naming individual fields and then passing that same name since it is so redundant and error prone. Thanks for clarifying.